# Hedging large single asset positions

Tags: finance, portfolio-optimization, trading, hedging

I recently came across an article that described how big market participants like GS, JPM, etc. take off large equity positions (block trades) of their clients, and putting that risk on their own balance sheet. Then they use their prop models to compute what assets they have to short to essentially be market/delta neutral again. I am mainly interested in how they do it using spot equities.

Does anyone know what sort of models are used in this case? I was thinking they were using some sort of portfolio optimisation models such as Hierarichal Risk Parity or minimum variance optimisation. Any help, resources, code is highly appreciated!